# Use delimiter to separate a pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file where I am trying to read string and integer input using a `Scanner`. I need to separate the data using a comma and there is also the issue of newline character. Here is the text file contents:

> John T Smith, 90
> Eric K Jones, 85

My code:

```
public class ReadData {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
      input.useDelimiter(",");
      while (input.hasNext()) {
          String name1 = input.next();
          int score1 = input.nextInt();
          System.out.println(name1+" "+score1);
      }
      input.close();
  }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at ReadData.main(ReadData.java:10)
```

Comment: Can you share the error logs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/13963086

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java,util.mismatchException

Comment: No, I mean can you edit the question and add the complete logs to help us understand that where exactly it went wrong

Comment: I have done so now. Sorry was having a problem copying from command prompt

Comment: Use ",|\\n" RegExp delimiter @Anesu Jambwa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the delimiter for class `java.util.Scanner` to comma (`,`) means that each call to method `next()` will read **all** the data up to the next comma, including newlines. Hence the call to `nextInt` reads the score **plus** the name on the next line and that isn't an `int`. Hence the `InputMismatchException`.

Just read the entire line and split it on the comma (`,`).
(Note: Below code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html))

```java
public class ReadData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
//            input.useDelimiter(","); <- not required
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                String name1 = parts[0];
                int score1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
                System.out.println(name1+" "+score1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you're a lifesaver. Never thought about passing it as a whole line String and then splitting it into an array 

Comment: You could use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use `",|\\n"` RegExp delimiter:

```
public class ReadData {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    input.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String name1 = input.next();
        int score1   = Integer.parseInt(input.next().trim());
        System.out.println(name1+" "+score1);
    }
    input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was very close to having the same code, only issue was I didn't invoke the trim method so I got a numberformatexception but thanks anyway. 

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String text = "John T Smith, 90\r\n"
            + "Eric K Jones, 85";
Scanner input = new Scanner(text);
input.useDelimiter(",\\s*|\\R");
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String name1 = input.next();
    int score1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(name1+" "+score1);
}
input.close();
```

output:

```
John T Smith 90
Eric K Jones 85
```